# How to remove warning for conversion in char array to unsigned char array

Tags: c, linux, types, casting, char

Hi i have the following code in c under Linux platform

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned char client_id[8];
  char id[17] = "00000001";
  sscanf(id,"%02X%02X%02X%02X", &client_id[0], &client_id[1], &client_id[2], &client_id[3]);
  printf("%02X%02X%02X%02X", client_id[0], client_id[1], client_id[2], client_id[3]);
}
```

When I run this code I get the output

```
00000001
```

but with following warning

```
> test.c: In function ‘main’: test.c:7:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects
> argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned
> char *’ [-Wformat=] 
> sscanf(id,"%02X%02X%02X%02X",&client_id[0],&client_id[1],&client_id[2],&client_id[3]);
> ^ test.c:7:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned
> int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘unsigned char *’ [-Wformat=]
> test.c:7:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned
> int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘unsigned char *’ [-Wformat=]
> test.c:7:1: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned
> int *’, but argument 6 has type ‘unsigned char *’ [-Wformat=]
```

The warnings are but obvious but how can I remove them?

I do not want to use

> -Wno-pointer-sign

Should I use `sprintf` or any changes in `sscanf`?

Comment: `unsigned int client_id[8];` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell `sscanf` that the arguments are of a `char` type.  This is done by putting the `hh` modifier before the `X` format specifier:

```
sscanf(id,"%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX",&client_id[0],&client_id[1],&client_id[2],&client_id[3]);
```